# AutoLayout: 3 views in controller

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

Here is the screenshot:[image]

How do I apply constraints, so that

1. the red view stays at same height, independent of 3.5 or 4 inch form factor
2. the green and blue are same width and same height
3. the green, blue and red have the standard spacing to the containing view
4. the red, green, blue have the spacing to each other
5. the green aligns to the red on the right side
6. the blue aligns to the red in the left side

The app runs only in portrait mode. XCode 5 and iOS 7.

Thanks

Comment: Which constraints are you having trouble with? Don't say all of them, because that would only be true if you tried absolutely nothing. If you say what you've done so far people will be more likely to help you.

Comment: And actually just try to add constraints according to your list. It should be really easy.

Comment: You have a numbered list of constraints for your view. Some of the items actually include more than one constraint but just go through your list one by one and add the constraints into the view.

Comment: I tried a few things. I am not sure, with what to start out first. With which view and with which constraint? Actually what is the best way to go about adding constraints in AutoLayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is so simple if you give it a try.

1. For red, fix its left, right & top value as in container.
2. For blue, fix left & bottom, similarly for green, fix right & bottom with respect to parent views.
3. Ctrl+drag from blue to green & select height option from popup. Next time repeat for width.
4. For red, fix the height from constraints.
5. ctrl+drag from blue to green & set its right position.
6. Ctrl+drag from green to red & select top position.

Let me know if it does not work for you.

Comment: Works exactly like you said. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

These constraints in visual format will do what you want...

```
@"|-[redView]-|"
@"|-[blueView]-[greenView(==blueView)]-|"
@"V:|-[redView(==100)]-[blueView]-|"
@"V:[redView]-[greenView]-|"
```

If you add this set of constraints (either in Interface Builder or code using `visualFormatLayout`) then you will get what you want.

Of course, these assume that you're just using the standard separator spacing and a red view height of 100.

The blue and green will then adjust their height according to the screen size.

This layout is really easy though. You should be able to work this out without asking. Just draw it on a piece of paper and work out what info the system needs to make it work.

In fact, in your question you have just provided a list of constraints for your view. Just use Interface Builder to insert those constraints one by one.